# difficulty loading content of a page

Tags: jquery

I am trying an ajax load on page but it not working. It displays some funny errors. I would paste the loader page. content to load and error below.

loader page

```
   <!doctype html>
<html lang=en>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/mobilethem.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/mobilethem.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.css" />

        <script src="themes/js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="themes/js/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function (){

    //alert("afdasdf");

    $('#load').click(function (){
    //alert("asdfsadf");
        $('#result').load("load.html");
    });
});
</script>
</head>

<body>

<div data-role="header">

<a href="#" id="load"> Load page</div>
</div>

<div data-role="content">

<div id="result"></div>

</div>


<div id="footer">

</div>

</body>

</html>
```

content to load
load.html

This is the content my friend. how do you want to make this happen

Error message in browser console

event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead. jquery-1.7.1.min.js:3
OPTIONS file:///C:/wamp/www/MyJqueryMobile/load.html No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. jquery-1.7.1.min.js:4
XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/wamp/www/MyJqueryMobile/load.html. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. loadpage.html:1

Comment: You are viewing the html file directly from file system and not using any server. now when you load another html from file system using jquery it is being blocked by CORS http://goo.gl/vSIhdR. This would work fine if you put the html on any server.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with `load.html`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your going to have to run that from your web server in order for it to work. Otherwise the browser sees you doing a cross site request.

Turn on your WAMP server and go to: `http://localhost/MyJqueryMobile/load.html` it should work.